# Rails 3: Can't seem to write cookies for top level domain :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, dns, subdomain

I setup the cookie store to domain => :all, like I could find in documentation and it seems to work, because devise's authentication works across the multiple domain.

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_MyApp.com_session', :domain => :all
```

However when I am trying myself to write to a cookie, it always write down the sub domain... I don't get it:

[image]

I write the cookie in the simplest manner possible:

```
 cookies.permanent[:remember_locale] = locale
```

But no matter what it won't set it for the top level domain whereas the one dropped by devise seems to manage it without a problem :(

Alex

ps: I am using rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 3):

The configuration for the session_store only applies to the session cookie.  When setting a separate cookie you have to specify the domain for that cookie as well.

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_locale] = { :value => locale, :domain => :all }
```

Note (pulled from rails source):

```
  # Please note that if you specify a :domain when setting a cookie, you must also specify the domain when deleting the cookie:
  #
  #  cookies[:key] = {
  #    :value => 'a yummy cookie',
  #    :expires => 1.year.from_now,
  #    :domain => 'domain.com'
  #  }
  #
  #  cookies.delete(:key, :domain => 'domain.com')
```